# Using jQuery, Slide content divs in and out of the same area using $.when().then()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menu, panel

Using some code from this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2546389/693706), I'm trying to develop a content slider similar to the one on this [web template](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/38395.html)

Here's the  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/broncozr/ZJYV8/) of my work.

You click on the links to show content; previously shown content is hidden before doing that. If some content is showing, it can be hidden manually by clicking on it.

Using the IDs of the links (A, B, etc.), we get the ID for the content (`<div>`) to show. When an element is shown, it is given the class, "elementEnabled," to identify it later.

I want the content that's being hidden to be out of the way before I slide in the new content. How do I do that in an orderly way? Is the `.delay()` that I have on the `.show()` a good way to do that?

Is there a more elegant way (in jQuery) to systematically hide the content that's shown and then show the appropriate content? Is there a better way to go than using  `$.when().then(function(){})` ??? Is it good practice to put that much code in a callback function (like below), or should I split the "show" part of the code into a separate function?

Thanks for any suggestions.

The HTML:

```
<div id="links">
<a href="#" id="a-link">A</a>
<a href="#" id="b-link">B</a>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
<div class="start-content" id="a">
content here
</div>    
<div class="content" id="b">
content here
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
$("#links a").click(function() {

//  having to do this for the callback function below
var park_this = $(this);

//  which ID is currently shown?
id_enabled = $('.enabledElement').attr("id").replace('-link', '');           

//hide previously displayed content
$.when($('#' + id_enabled).stop().hide("slide", 
    { direction: "left" }, 400)).then( function(){ // callback 

// remove any instances of special class
$('.enabledElement').removeClass('enabledElement');

// add special class to clicked element 
park_this.addClass('enabledElement');

// using the link ID, get the ID of the content to show
var id = park_this.attr("id").replace('-link', ''); //matching id

//show what's clicked on
$('#' + id).stop().delay(initial_pause).show("slide", 
    { direction: "left" }, 1000 );    

});  // close when/then callback function

} // close "click" function
```

Comment: `when` and `then` are for deferring, mostly for ajax requests, what you need is just a basic callback if I'm not mistaken, not that the deferring methods won't work, but what was the problem with the built in callbacks? Adding too much code in a callback is not an issue (unless it's actually so much it slows down the site, callback or not).

Comment: I'm not real familiar w/ jQuery's methods. I tried to wrap all of the `show()` section in a `callback()` function after the `hide()` section, but I was getting a "stack overflow/exceeded" error. I don't know if it was creating an infinite loop or what was happening? That was the main reason I went to the `when`/`then`.